# appengine website very slow processing requests

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a website deployed on appengine that has a API.
On my computer I have a node.js script that sends data to the website using a POST through the API.

The problem is that while sometimes the website processes the requests fast (average of 1 per second), some other times it is very slow (average of 1 request per minute).

After some digging, I've found out that when that happens, 4 requests are processes very fast, and then the website does nothing for 4 minutes, repeating the process all over again, making the average time of 1 request per minute like said before. What could be causing this?

I don't know if it is very relevant or not, but I have a free appengine account.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in your node.js script.
The Appengine has a limit of 60 seconds for external requests - its not possible that one 
request blocks an instance for more than these 60 seconds. (And even if the instance is blocked,
the gae would spawn another one)

Other guesses:

- check the access logs for first/warmup requests (eg. slow instance startup)
- check the access-log to ensure that the gae actually recived the requests